# Symfony 1.4: Override doctrine:build-schema command

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, command-line-interface

Is it possible to override a Symfony 1.4 CLI command?

More specifically, I was wondering if it's possible to override this command:

```
php symfony doctrine:build-schema
```

What I want to do is to add a new option in the database.yml file for each connection I find in it.
The option I want to add is a package option
So, an hypothetical connection could be:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    package: myPackageOption
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name'
      username: db_user
      password: db_password
```

If it would be possible, where can i find the code to override?

Comment: I will say *yes*. But what do you want to achieve at the end?

Comment: ...I'd like to add some other options to the database.yml, so when I run the build-schema command it "use" the new options

Comment: I never do that, but I think you will have to dig into the Doctrine generation to override what you want. But maybe you can add more information in your question about what you want to add in `database.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use some shell script that pre-generate the databses.yml and then auto-invoque the php symfony doctrine:build-schema. Something like:

build.sh, in project root folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp config/databases_1.yml config/databases.yml
php symfony doctrine:build
```

then, type ./build.sh (after added execution permissions) in your console.

The copy/replace of multiple databases_xxx.yml it's the easiest example. But you can do any processing you want.

If you don't know about shell scripting, you can do the file modification even with a php script, so your build.sh should looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
php pregenerate_databases.php
php symfony doctrine:build
```

Comment: Wait a moment, I'd already be able to write some shell script, but my problem is not that. My question is: is possible to ovverride the symfony's built-in command doctrine:build-schema and, if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to override the task but I can't make it work, but:

You can create your own task that inherits the doctrine task and do your stuff:
in lib/task add sfDoctrineBuildSchemaCustomTask.class.php:

```
class sfDoctrineBuildSchemaCustomTask extends sfDoctrineBuildSchemaTask
{
  /**
   * @see sfTask
   */
  protected function configure()
  {
    $this->addOptions(array(
      new sfCommandOption('application', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_OPTIONAL, 'The application name', true),
      new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', 'dev'),
    ));

    $this->namespace = 'doctrine';
    $this->name = 'build-schema-custom';
    $this->briefDescription = 'Creates a schema from an existing database';

    $this->detailedDescription = <<<EOF
The [doctrine:build-schema|INFO] task introspects a database to create a schema:

  [./symfony doctrine:build-schema|INFO]

The task creates a yml file in [config/doctrine|COMMENT]
EOF;
  }

  /**
   * @see sfTask
   */
  protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
  {
        // do your stuff before original call
    parent::execute($arguments,$options);
        // do your stuff after original call

  }
}
```

Then, you can call php symfony doctrine:build-schema-custom, and go!

---

Or, maybe, you can edit the original task located in lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBuildSchemaTask.class.php